# What kind of tree is this!

Tags: trees

My husband brought home a branch of this tree but we can’t figure out what it is!!

[image][image][image]

[image]

Comment: If no  one gives an accurate ID, it would be useful to have a photo of the tree itself as well as the ones you've  posted - what part of the world are you in?

Comment: California, unfortunately I am unable to get a picture of the tree.

Comment: To me it remembers a Fraxinus (ash). Was the plant heavy cut? (and maybe some herbicide)? Or maybe this is just one ruined branch? So to me it seems much more a monstrosity/defect (some plants do it, when heavily disturbed: a reaction which make the tree to growth too many new buds, branches, flowers from a single point).

Comment: All 3 pictures of the same tree branch? Top one looks like Eucalyptus seed-"buttons". Middle one looks like ...Chia pet?

Comment: Here’s a pic of the actual tree, it’s not the best. But all we were able to get before leaving

Comment: As I indicate in an answer, I think it is a bottlebrush tree, not sure which species yet. If you still have the fruiting capsules, could you tease away the top 4 flaps on one? Underneath should be a round hole from which the seeds are dispersed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm tempted to suggest this is a bottlebrush tree (Callistemon or Melaleuca); Callistemon is on the list of recommended species for street trees in San Francisco. The green flowers in pic 2 are found in Callistemon even though the pink and red species are far more showy; the flowers are arranged rather raggedly on the stem and the seed capsules in pic 1 are not as regularly arranged on the twig as would be normal for Callistemon. Another worrying detail is that the capsules appear to be 4-part where many Callistemon are 3-part. So Callistemon might not exactly be our guy but I think maybe close.

Edit: I came across [this image](http://anpsa.org.au/jpg2/bullich1.jpg) from Australian Plants Online which is much in accordance with @LorelC observation in the comments about Eucalyptus. Which one though is not certain.

Answer (score 1):

Eucalyptus sinuosa
"Octopus mallee"
there is a chance it is a related species.
In any case, native to western australia